# json data not being passed in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a very simple ajax call with Rails 4, but the json response is not being retrieved properly.

Here's the script:

```
$(document).on "submit", "form[name=upvote-form]", ->
  form = $(this)
  $.post "/vote", $(this).serialize(), (data) ->
    if data["status"] is true
      form.find("input").addClass "disabled"
      $("#vote-count-".concat(form.find("#question_id").attr("value"))).html data["votes"]
    else

    return

  return
```

`alert(data['votes'])` is `undefined`, which made me try to find what was going wrong.

Then in the console I could see this:

```
ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):
  app/controllers/vote_controller.rb:8:in `vote'
```

And here's the method with the problem:

```
class VoteController < ApplicationController

    def vote
        question_id = params[:question][:id]
        user_id = current_user.id
        vote = Vote.where(["question_id = :q", { q: question_id }]).where(["user_id = :u", { u: user_id }]).take
        respond_to do |format|
            if vote.nil?
                @vote = Vote.new
                @vote.question = Question.find question_id
                @vote.user = User.find user_id
                @vote.save
                votes = Vote.where(["question_id = :q", { q: question_id }]).count
                format.json { render :json => { status: true, votes: votes } }
            else
                format.json { render :json => { status: false } }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Any clue of what's going wrong? And what can I do?

Comment: I think it's because you're not passing a resource to `respond_with` and it can't determine the location. Try changing that to `respond_to` or pass the `:location` option to `respond_with`. [Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) is meant to be used with a resource. Example

```
def show
  @vote = Vote.find params[:id]
  respond_with(@vote)
end
```

In your case, you need to use the `respond_to` method

```
def vote
  # stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    if vote.nil?
      # stuff
      format.json { render json: { status: true, votes: votes } }
    else
      # other stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I do that most times I am getting (`ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/vote_controller.rb:7:in 'vote')`

Comment: sure, I just uploaded it

Comment: I can see a really weird behaviouor. Most of the times the success post function is not executed (basically it disables the upvote button and updates the vote count),but some times when I hit the upvote button it works!

Comment: The error is a result of not having an appropriate response for the _else_ condition. If the vote _isn't_ nil, what should happen?

Comment: nothing, the else condition will never be executed because the upvote button will be disabled if the user tries to vote that item

Comment: ok, now for some reason with the edits I made (see modified code) the upvote button is always disabled, but only few times the vote count is updated. Why?

Comment: Clearly that's not the case as that is precisely what is happening in your code. Try adding an `else` with the following `format.json { head :ok }`

Comment: that did the same thing than before, only a few times the button is disabled and the vote count updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65241/discussion-between-bart-jedrocha-and-dabadaba).